# Hello world linking issue (ASM)

Tags: windows, assembly, linker, nasm

Okay, today I'm trying to learn some asm.

I'm using nasm and go link. This hello world seems to work fine:

```
bits 32
extern _MessageBoxA@16
extern _ExitProcess@4

section .data
    title db 'Somme message',0 
    message db 'Hello World!',0 

section .text
global _start
_start:
    push dword 0            ; Type = MB_OK
    push dword title            ; Caption
    push dword message             ; Message
    push dword 0            ; Handle = NULL
    call _MessageBoxA@16

    push dword 0            ; Exit Code = EXIT_SUCCESS
    call _ExitProcess@4
```

I can build it with:
    nasm -fwin32 test.asm
    golink /entry _start /mix test.obj user32.dll, kernel32.dll

Now my question is: can I build it using alink instead of golink ? if yes, how can I do that ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes... but you may need to alter your source slightly... and you may need a library to link against. Alink is somewhat "obsolete" these days, though it still works. I'm running Linux and haven't done Windows for a long time. The guys who are doing Windows these days seem to prefer GoLink. Unless you have some reason to prefer Alink, I'd stick with GoLink. (One advantage is that we have source to Alink - I can even run it on Linux! Can't run the resulting executable of course...). If you really need it, I might be able to dig up some obsolete code that used to work... but I'd stick to GoLink. (Pelle's PoLink should also work, and probably MS's Link as well).

Comment: Well thanks for the info. I'll try Ms's Link.exe , and eventually I'll continue to use GoLink ! Thanks man!